# How to delete specific part of line starting with './.../.../' in command line using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, command

I'm trying to write regular expression which will delete part with path file.

I've already tried using "grep -v -o '/.' a.txt > b.txt", but it's not working.

Input:

```
 324   ./Users/.../something
 85444 ./App/.../something
```

And all I want to do is output:

```
324
854444
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just search for numeric values by providing a regex

```
 grep -E '\d+' -o a.txt > b.txt
```

This will give you the result you wanted.

If the numbers are definitely in the beginning of the line, you can add and anchor:

```
 grep -E '^\d+' -o a.txt > b.txt
```

or if you may have some spaces before the numbers:

```
 grep -E '^\s*\d+' -o a.txt > b.txt
```

Comment: I thought about this, but files can have numeric values in their names too

Comment: @appendix Anchor it: `^\d+`

Comment: Thaaaank you very much!

Comment: Using `^\d+` will only work when intended data to retain is only digits that too from very start of line but if it can be any data other than digits, then you need a better regex.

Comment: I added the anchor to the answer as well, thank you @vintnes